# PreSignUP failed with error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443 in AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to AWS Cognito OAuth 2.0 Client credentials Flow to get the access token,
my code is as follows, I have tried running this on postman and it works, I generated the code to see how the request is being structured, replicated the same thing with node HTTPS, so that I can write it in the lambda function, but it's not working as I keep getting connection refused error

```
"use strict";
const https = require("https");
const accessToken = null;

//the client credentials and client secret
const client_id = "xxxxxxx";
const client_secret = "xxxxxxxx";

const secretAndID = `${client_id}:${client_secret}`;
let bufferObj = Buffer.from(secretAndID, "utf-8");
let base64string = bufferObj.toString("base64");
console.log("base 64 string", base64string);

var accessOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://xxxxxxx-dev.auth.eu-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    Authorization: `Basic ${base64string}`,
  },
};

//the accessToken generator runner
const accessTokenPayload = {
  grant_type: "client_credentials",
  scope: "",
  client_id: 'xxxxxx'
};

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
const aToken = https.request(accessOptions, (res) => {
  let body = "";
  console.log("access token generator status:", res.statusCode);
  console.log("access token generator Response:", res);
  console.log("Headers:", JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding("utf8");
  res.on("data", (chunk) => (body += chunk));
  res.on("end", () => {
    console.log("Successfully processed HTTPS response");
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("The access token generator body", body);
    callback(null, event);
  });
});

aToken.on("error", callback);
aToken.write(JSON.stringify(accessTokenPayload));
aToken.end();
}
```

I am always getting this error `message: "PreSignUp failed with error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443."`

Comment: It appears that your presignup Cognito trigger isn't set up correctly as it's trying to connect to localhost.  How is your trigger configured?

Comment: @stdunbar the presignup trigger is called preAuthLambda and it's selected under the lambda function in the pre-sign-up triggers basically. 

At first, the particular lambda function was used to store the user email and name to our database, and I was generating the access token manually and using it in the process.env.accessToken.

Answer (score 1):

So I have been able to solve my problem, apparently, the use of HTTPS requires that you break down the URL in this form port, hostname, and path before it can work

so I converted this right here to

```
var accessOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://xxxxxxx-dev.auth.eu-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    Authorization: `Basic ${base64string}`,
  },
};
```

i converted the above code to

```
var accessOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  port: 443,
  hostname: "xxxasdax.amazoncognito.com",
  path: '/oauth2/token',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": `Basic ${process.env.base64String}`,
  },
};
```

Now this solved the problem of the connection being refused.

one other thing i had to do was to encodeURI of the data i was sending, rather than send a `JSON.stringify(payload)`,  i had to do the following

```
const bodyData = `${encodeURI('grant_type')}=${encodeURI(data.grant_type)}&${encodeURI('scope')}=${encodeURI(data.scope)}`;
```

this is me converting my payload to a querystring because the content-type accepted is  `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",`